# Python list comprehension: list sub-items without duplicates

Tags: python

I am trying to print all the letters in all the words in a list, without duplicates. I tried:

```
>>> wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
>>> letterlist = []
>>> [[letterlist.append(x) for x in y] for y in wordlist]
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None]]
>>> letterlist
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

The desired result is `['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']` instead.

How do I modify the list comprehension to remove duplicates?

Comment: so you want to use list comprehension only ?

Comment: You can do `[letterlist.append(x) for y in wordlist for x in y if x not in letterlist]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit you own code:

```
[[letterlist.append(x) for x in y if x not in letterlist] for y in wordlist]
```

or

```
list(set([[letterlist.append(x) for x in y if x not in letterlist] for y in wordlist]))
```

else:

```
list(set(''.join(wordlist)))
```

Answer (score 10):

Do you care about maintaining order?

```
>>> wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
>>> set(''.join(wordlist))
{'o', 'i', 'g', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', 't', 'r'}
```

Comment: This can be written as `set().union(*wordlist)` which allows `set` to take care of the multiple iterables and doesn't require joining them to a string first

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches:

Preserving order:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(wordlist)))
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

If you're not fussed about order:

```
>>> list(set().union(*wordlist))
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'o', 'r', 't']
```

Neither of this are using list-comps for side effects, eg:

```
[[letterlist.append(x) for x in y] for y in wordlist]
```

Is building a list of lists of `Nones` purely to mutate `letterlist`

Answer (score 3):

While all other answers don't maintain order, this code does:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
letterlist = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(letterlist))
```

See also, an article about several ways with benchmarks: [Fastest way to uniqify a list in Python](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark).

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work: `>>> wordlist = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(wordlist))
>>> wordlist
['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']`

Comment: Please note that my code uses 'letterlist' rather than 'wordlist' which your code uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to remove the duplicates but the order is not maintained.

```
>>> letterlist = list({x for y in wordlist for x in y})
>>> letterlist
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'o', 'r', 't']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
s = set()
[[s.add(x) for x in y] for y in wordlist]
```